# RSASSA-PSS in TLS 1.2

Tags: signature, tls, certificates, rsa-pss

I know it is possible to use RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 with client certificates in TLS 1.3.
But what about the other way around: using RSASSA-PSS with client certificates in TLS 1.2?

Is it possible to use RSASSA-PSS signed certificates with TLS 1.2 at all? Do I have to fall-back to RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 during handshake?

I searched through the RFC5246 but was not able to find anything that answers my questions.

Comment: You didn't miss anything; RFC 5246 did not have PSS. RFC8446 4.2.3 requires 1.3 implementations that negotiate down to 1.2 support PSS; dupe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/79665/on-what-basis-is-padding-chosen-in-openssl . For Java in particular, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61676711/how-to-add-signature-algorithm-from-one-provider-to-another-provider-used-during https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688276/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-server-certificate-signature-algorithm-rsas

Comment: I've not closed it as a dupe as I think an even more detailed answer would be possible. Client auth is more or less an add-on to the handshake. Generally you would need to discuss with the other party to include client auth anyway (due to the trust of specific client certificate chains). I don't see any specific problems by just using PSS in TLS 1.2 in that case... just test if it works on both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client announces in the `Signature Algorithm Extension` that it supports one of the RSA-PSS:

```
rsa_pss_rsae_sha256(0x0804),
rsa_pss_rsae_sha384(0x0805),
rsa_pss_rsae_sha512(0x0806),
```

then server may choose this even in TLS1.2.
=> Yes, it's possible to use RSA-PSS with TLS1.2.

The main difference beside the different preencoding is, that RSA-PSS in TLS1.2 needs the handshake message content instead of the constructed data (containing `TLS 1.3, server CertificateVerify`).

If the client does not announce these RSA-PSS signature algorithms, the server must not use these.